# make cannot find target link library

Tags: gcc, cmake, makefile

I am cloned [g2o repository](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o). Run cmake and make inside its build folder:

```
g2o/build$ cmake ..
g2o/build$ make
g2o/build$ make install
```

Then wanted to run [simple optimizer](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/tree/master/g2o/examples/simple_optimize) example.

I modified [its CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/g2o/examples/simple_optimize/CMakeLists.txt) to following:

```
include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++17" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX17)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX17)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++17")
   add_definitions(-DCOMPILEDWITHC17)
   message(STATUS "Using flag -std=c++17.")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
   add_definitions(-DCOMPILEDWITHC11)
   message(STATUS "Using flag -std=c++11.")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
   add_definitions(-DCOMPILEDWITHC0X)
   message(STATUS "Using flag -std=c++0x.")
else()
   message(FATAL_ERROR "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()

find_package(g2o REQUIRED)
include_directories(${G2O_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_package(Eigen3 3.1.0 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

link_directories(/ws/gps-imu-calib/g2o/build/lib)

add_executable(simple_optimize
  simple_optimize.cpp
)

set_target_properties(simple_optimize PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME simple_optimize)

target_link_libraries(simple_optimize core solver_eigen ${EIGEN3_LIBS} ${G2O_CORE_LIBRARY})
target_link_libraries(simple_optimize types_slam2d)
target_link_libraries(simple_optimize types_slam3d)
```

While then created build folder inside simple_optimize and run cmake and make inside it similar to above. cmake succeeds, but make gives following error:

```
Scanning dependencies of target simple_optimize
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/simple_optimize.dir/simple_optimize.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable simple_optimize
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcore
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsolver_eigen
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltypes_slam2d
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -ltypes_slam3d
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/simple_optimize.dir/build.make:84: simple_optimize] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:76: CMakeFiles/simple_optimize.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:84: all] Error 2
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: Uh, doesn't it [build the examples by default](https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L271-L274)? Try looking in `build/g2o/examples/simple_optimize`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `find_package(g2o REQUIRED)` to access an installed g2o library, please note that `core`, `solver_eigen`, etc. are not defined. Those are targets defined only when you compile g2o source code.

There are three ways to do:

1. Compile your code as part of g2o by running `cmake -DG2O_BUILD_EXAMPLES ..` in `g2o/build`. This is @Botje's comment.
2. Compile your code with g2o as a submodule, by add `add_subdirectory(thirdpart/g2o)` to your `CMakeLists.txt`. Then `core`, `solver_eigen` etc. will be visible in your `CMakeLists.txt` as well.
3. Compile your code with `find_package(g2o REQUIRED)`. Then you need a different library target for g2o:

```
find_package(g2o REQUIRED)
include_directories(${G2O_INCLUDE_DIR}). # Note: G2O_INCLUDE_DIRS is not defined

find_package(Eigen3 3.1.0 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIR})

link_directories(/ws/gps-imu-calib/g2o/build/lib)

add_executable(simple_optimize
  simple_optimize.cpp
)

set_target_properties(simple_optimize PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME simple_optimize)

target_link_libraries(simple_optimize ${G2O_CORE_LIBRARY} ${G2O_SOLVER_EIGEN} ${EIGEN3_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(simple_optimize ${G2O_TYPES_SLAM2D})
target_link_libraries(simple_optimize ${G2O_TYPES_SLAM3D})
```

Check https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/blob/master/cmake_modules/FindG2O.cmake